# Selenium driver: -Dwebdriver.driver="iexplorer" invokes safari

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

When I try to run my Serenity test automation, I called following maven command:

```
mvn clean verify -Dentry_point="**/*SmokeTestSuite.java" -Dwebdriver.driver="iexplorer" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="<my path>\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

I supplied the iexplorer as the driver and the path to the IEDriverServer.exe. My Internet Explorer version is 11.x. 
It errors out that I need to add the path to safari.exe when I am running the ie driver.

Follows is error stack trace :

```
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:128)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:142)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:133)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:103)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getTitle(WebDriverFacade.java:213)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityReporter.managedDriverIsNotAlive(SerenityReporter.java:215)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityReporter.beforeScenario(SerenityReporter.java:188)
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter.beforeScenario(DelegatingStoryReporter.java:55)
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConcurrentStoryReporter.beforeScenario(ConcurrentStoryReporter.java:158)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:877)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.performScenarios(PerformableTree.java:811)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:784)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:416)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:387)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:291)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) .                                
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Safari could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''Safari.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Safari like this:
*safari c:\blah\Safari.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.locators.SingleBrowserLocator.findBrowserLocationOrFail(SingleBrowserLocator.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:53)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.strategies.InternetExplorerDriverBuilder.newInstance(InternetExplorerDriverBuilder.java:30)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:116)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webdriver.driver` is the correct Serenity property to set the driver. I'm not sure what DebajanB means by "error-prone" - as a rule, it works or it doesn't, and if it doesn't, it's a configuration issue. To check that the driver property is configured correctly in Maven (you may need to pass it into your tests as a system property in the surefire or failsafe plugin), see if it works with firefox.

The references to webdriver.gecko.driver etc tell Serenity where to find the binary for a particular driver, but they do not tell Serenity which driver to use. You can have several driver binaries configured, and then chose to use one or the other with `webdriver.driver`.

Safari is not the default driver for Serenity, Firefox is, so the reference to Safari is curious. It may be a defect/misleading error message from an older version - are you using the latest version of Serenity?

Comment: I set <webdriver.driver>iexplorer</webdriver.driver> in failsafe plugin but it's gaves same error. Right now I am using serenity version 1.1.39, it is a fairly old version, might the cause of the misleading error as you suggested.

Comment: updating serenity to 1.2.2 did resolve the above issue. But now internet explorer keeps messaging out "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server"

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
```

...implies that the program was unable to create/spawn a desired new *InternetExplorerDriver* instance.

The main reason of this error is the **error prone *maven*** command you have used to execute the *Serenity Test Automation Suite* which is as follows :

```
mvn clean verify -Dentry_point="**/*SmokeTestSuite.java" -Dwebdriver.driver="iexplorer" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="<my path>\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

The most commonly used *WebDriver* variants are :

- **`-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver`** - For **`geckodriver.exe`**
- **`-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver`** - For **`chromedriver.exe`**
- **`-Dwebdriver.ie.driver`** - For **`IEDriverServer.exe`**

But as you have used an incorrect *argument* as **`-Dwebdriver.driver`** along with an incorrect *value* as **`iexplorer`** the *Serenity Test Automation Framework* tries to access the default configuration of **Safari.exe**.

### Solution

You need to remove the *error prone* argument **`-Dwebdriver.driver="iexplorer"`** and you will be through.

Comment: I tried removing it, then it defaults to firefox browser